# Adpatar UserControl al tamaño de la ventana padre

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

¿Como puedo hacer para que al maximizar la ventana padre de mi aplicación la ventana hija, que esta diseñada en un userControl se adapte y ocupe todo el stackPanel al que esta conteniendolo?

Para muestra un Boton (nunca mejor dicho);

UserControl (ventana hija)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la ventana principal, el `stackPanel` marcado es el que ocupara el `UserControl`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es el siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría es que el `ControlTab` ocupase siempre el alto máximo de la ventana padre

Comment: ¿Algun experto en la materia? :D

Comment: Crea un *Panel* con la propiedad *Dock* en *Top* y ahí metes el botón. Después al *TabControl* le pones la propiedad *Dock* como *Fill*, con lo que te ocupará todo el espacio libre.